# Does python sleep function affect GPIO output?

Tags: gpio, python, raspbian-jessie

I am using a sensor with a Raspberry Pi to monitor a process (temperature) every second.

I have an LED to indicate if the value is above 50 degrees. And the LED should remain ON for the next 10 seconds if the temperature is above 50. As the measurement is every second, I am using `time.sleep(1.0)`.

Everything works fine except there is a flickering of the LED. Is it because of sleep function? Later, I will have to add some relay control instead of LED. So I doubt that the flickering (possibly caused by pin voltage variation) will affect relay operation. Any suggestions, please.

```
#First measurement, not shown here
#check if value is higher than 50
if (self.measurement >50 ):
     Timer = 0
     while (Timer <=10):
           self.pi.write(20,1)   #set LED HIGH
           time.sleep(1.0)   #is flickering because of this sleep fn?
           Timer +=1
           # remaining code to continue measurement inside while loop , not shown
```

Comment: Code snippets are almost never enough to diagnose a problem.  We need a complete script which shows the problem.

Comment: Nothing changes while a process is sleeping (unless you're using threading). Look at it as though the computer reaches the sleep command an internal clock starts. When the clock stops it runs the next thing after the sleep command. Threading is a system to get two processes running in parallel. BTW, Jessie is end-of-life, the time to upgrade to Buster is NOW!